# Adding an object to object array in java

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, object

i have a class named ChargingPoint and i created a 2 objects arrays of ChargingPoint in a class named fuelSt
In the class FuelSt i created an object named charg1 so that i can add objects to the arrays
In the main im creating 4 ChargingPoints
2 that have the letter f and needs to be added to the array arrFast
2 who have the letter u and needs to be added to the array arrUs

somehow its showing me only the last element multiple times and i dont understand why
thank u in advance

im trying the put 2 objects in arrFast
and 2 objects in arrUs

```
**ChargingPoint class=**
public class ChargingPoint {

    private double kw;
    private double trf;
    private char isFast;
    private String code;
    
   
    
    
    public ChargingPoint (String code,char isFast) {
    this.code = code;
    this.isFast = isFast;
    trf = 1.5;
    
    
    }
    public void setTRF(double trf ) {
        if(trf >=0) {
            this.trf = trf;
            
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Error,invaild input");
        }
    }
    public void setKW(double kw) {
        if(kw >=0) {
            this.kw= kw;
            
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Error,invaild input");
        
        }
        }

    public double getKW() {
        return kw;
    }
    public double getTRF() {
        return trf;
    }
    public char getISFAST() {
    return isFast;
    }
    public String getCODE() {
        return code;
    }
    public double consumptionTotal(double KW,double TRF) {
        double sum;
        this.kw = KW;
        this.trf = TRF;
        sum = (TRF*KW);
        return sum;
    }
    public void print(){
        System.out.println("kw =" + kw + ", trf =" + trf + ", isFast =" + isFast + ", code =" + code);
        
    }
    public ChargingPoint() {
    }
    public char getIsFast() {
        return isFast;
        
    }
    
    public double consumptionTotal() {
        return (trf*kw);
    }
   public String toString() {
        return "kw: "+this.kw+" "+"isfast: "+this.isFast + " "+"code: "+this.code;
     }
```

```
**FuelSt class=**
public class FuelSt {
    
    private ChargingPoint[] arrUs;
    private int currentUs ;
    private ChargingPoint[] arrFast;
    private int currentFt ;
    private boolean highway = true;
    ChargingPoint charg1 = new ChargingPoint();
    ChargingPoint charg2 = new ChargingPoint();
    
 
   
    
    public FuelSt (boolean highway) {
        if(highway = true) {
            this.highway = highway;
            double c;
            c = charg1.consumptionTotal();
            c = c -((c*13)/100);
        }
        else {
            this.highway =false;
        }
        

    }
    
   
    public boolean addChargingPoint (ChargingPoint charg1){
        //ChargingPoint[] arrFast = new ChargingPoint[30];
        //ChargingPoint[] arrUs = new ChargingPoint[30];
    
        if(charg1.getIsFast() == 'f') {
            if(arrFast == null) {
            arrFast = new ChargingPoint[30];
            }
            else {

            for(int i=0; i < arrFast.length;i++) {
                  arrFast[i] = charg1; 
                 
                

                
                }
            }
            }
            else if (charg1.getIsFast() == 'u') {
            if(arrUs == null) {
                arrUs = new ChargingPoint[30];
                }
            else {
            for(int i=0; i < arrUs.length;i++) {
                arrUs[i] = charg1;
                currentUs++;
                
         }
            }
            }
            



            
        return false;
}
```

```
**Main=**
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         System.out.print("is the fuel next to a highway?");  
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean yes = in.nextBoolean();
         
        FuelSt fuelroad = new FuelSt(yes);
        
     
        System.out.println("type kw");
        double kw = in.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("type u/f");
        char isFast = (char)System.in.read();
        System.out.println("type code");
        String code = in.next();
        ChargingPoint chargF= new ChargingPoint(code,isFast);
        chargF.setKW(kw);
        fuelroad.addChargingPoint(chargF);
        chargF.print();
        
        System.out.println("type kw");
        double kw1 = in.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("type u/f");
        char isFast1 = (char)System.in.read();
        System.out.println("type code");
        String code1 = in.next();
        ChargingPoint chargF1= new ChargingPoint(code1,isFast1);
        chargF1.setKW(kw1);
        fuelroad.addChargingPoint(chargF1);
        
        chargF1.print();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(fuelroad.getarrFast()));
        //System.out.println(fuelroad.getarrFast());
        
    
    
        
          
            System.out.println("type kw");
            double kw2 = in.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("type u/f");
            char isFast2 = (char)System.in.read();
            System.out.println("type code");
            String code2 = in.next();
            ChargingPoint chargU = new ChargingPoint(code2,isFast2);
            chargU.setKW(kw2);
            fuelroad.addChargingPoint(chargU);
            chargU.print();
            
            
            System.out.println("type kw");
            double kw3 = in.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("type u/f");
            char isFast3 = (char)System.in.read();
            System.out.println("type code");
            String code3 = in.next();
            ChargingPoint chargU1 = new ChargingPoint(code3,isFast3);
            chargU1.setKW(kw3);
            fuelroad.addChargingPoint(chargU1);
            chargU1.print();
```

Comment: What do you think that `for(int i=0; i < arrFast.length;i++) { arrFast[i] = charg1; }` does? (A) set some entry of `arrFast` to `charg1`, (B) set all entries of `arrFast` to `charg1`?

Comment: so how can i refer each time to a diffrent object?

Comment: You could for example use an additional field per array that contains the first free index (`int arrFastFirstFree` and `int arrUsFirstFree`). Or your for loop could check the entry in the array and if it is null then store the object at that position and stop the loop. Or you could use a pre-made helper class like `java.util.ArrayList`

Comment: Instead of filling the array completely with the current value each time (which is exactly what the `For loop` does) you should write the current value into the current array element! So eg `arrUs[currentUs++] = charg1;` ... btw write `If (highway == true)` or better `if (highway)` but not `if (highway = true)`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you are setting every entry in your array to charg1 inside the for loops.
If you want to use an array here you could do something like this:

```
for(int i = 0, i < arrFast.length(); i++) {
    if (arrFast[i] == null) {
        arrFast[i] = charg1;
        break;
    }
}
```

Here you iterate through the array, check for each entry, if it is free and set the first free entry to charg1, but there might still be the case, that the array is full, in which case it would remain unchanged.

What I'd rather suggest, is that you use an ArrayList instead:

```
private ArrayList<ChargingPoint> listFast = new ArrayList<ChargingPoint>(); // Create a new ArrayList to store your ChargingPoints
listFast.add(charg1) // Add a new ChargingPoint to the ArrayList
```

That way you don't have to worry about the list getting full. You can also remove entries from the list using .remove() and some other useful stuff.

Comment: i tried both ways but it still showing me the same problem, what can possibly be wrong?